# How to delete cache image from volley android

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I have created volleySingleton Class. I load image from ImageLoader . I have a requirement of deleting the cache but not able do that. Used all these three method

1) Deleting cache for particular URL : Use remove() to delete cache of an URL.

VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(ImageUrl);

2) Deleting all the cache :

VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();

3) VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().invalidate(ImageUrl,true);

I have tried all of them but cache is not getting deleted  Plz help

Comment: can i see the code where you are calling this.

Comment: public void imageSetter(String ImageUrl, final ImageView shopImageView){
ImageLoader imageLoader =
VolleySingleton.getInstance().getmImageLoader();    VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(ImageUrl);
         
VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().invalidate(ImageUrl,true);
         
VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
         if(ImageUrl!=null&&!ImageUrl.equals("null")) {
             imageLoader.get(ImageUrl.replaceAll("\\s", "%20"), new
ImageLoader.ImageListener() {I m Looding my image image with url}